# Установка линукс и состояние жесткого диска

Tags: linux, установка

Хочу поставить две ос. Создаю диск специально под Линукс, а когда я выбираю куда ставить линукс все мои томы в один соединяются(фото). Как их разделить? Видит диск С(160 Гб) и Диски D E F(340 гб)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какие две системы вы хотите поставить?

Comment: Диск вы как создавали? Нужно в винде просто отщепить кусок свободного места, не назначая на него метку тома и файловую систему

Comment: По скрину мне кажется что там есть 4 раздела на одном диске. Не вижу заявленного объединения в один...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов два системных, а в 338520 мб 3 диска лежат

Comment: @excellproj линукс и windows

Comment: Что значит "в один соединяются" я на картинке вижу 4 раздела, правда все они не подходят для установки linux, т.к. для линкса нужен как минимум один раздел (ext2,3,4 или xfs) и очень желательно еще один раздел типа swap (размером кол-во ОЗУ*2)

Comment: @RomanDanilov что значит отщипнуть ? Создавать с ним том?

Comment: в 338520 не может 3 диска лежать, там файловая система указана ntfs, а не расширенный раздел

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич Диск один - WD5000 на 500 гигов. И 4 раздела линух видит, не вижу объединения.

Comment: @Mike ой, 3 тома. Прошу прощение

Comment: @Mike а как создать ещё один раздел?

Comment: никак. у вас уже есть 4 раздела, это максимум. вам надо удалить минимум один из них (желательно тот который самый большой, данные из него конечно пропадут если они есть) и на его месте создать "расширенный раздел", внутри которого вы сможете создать еще до 4х разделов

Comment: Зачем же так кромсать диск. Если на диске нет важной информации, то удалите все раздели и сделайте разметку по новой. К примеру два раздела для Linux и Windows или 3 для Linux, Swap(файл подкачки для Linux) и Windows

Comment: @excellproj ,я просто хочу поставить линуху((

Comment: @excellproj, так а чем отличаются томы и разделы?

Comment: @Mike скорее всего за "диски" были приняты дисковод и картридер

Comment: А зачем создавать ещё один вопрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для установки Linux выберите раздел на который хотите установить( к примеру `sda4`) и нажмите `Изменить`.
Выберите тип файловой системы, к примеру `Ext4` и точка монтирования `/` и отмечаете форматировать. Нажимаете OK и продолжаете установку. Но помните, что все данные будут удалены.